# How to implement a Stanley Controller on a Differential Drive?

Tags: robotics

I am currently trying to program autonomous algorithms for a differential drive base robot, and one of the path tracking algorithms that I researched and really wanted to implement was the Stanley method. However, the Stanley Method is only made for Ackermann steering vehicles (like cars), and I only have a differential drive robot. Is there any way I can implement this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Currently, what I thought about was converting Ackermann drive kinematics into differential drive kinematics. For example, if the Stanley Controller outputs a steering angle of 30 degrees, I would calculate the speed needed for each side of the differential drive to create the arc made by a car steered 30 degrees. However, I do not know how to do the math for this.